# couldnot transfer artifacts to central repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

Am running maven release through perform maven release,maven release build fails, but tags created except target folder.please help me to solve this, and also how to make maven build success.

**The console error shows**:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project Boom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.boom:Boom:war:1.7 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): TransferFailedException: ClientProtocolException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.  The cause lists the reason the original request failed.
>    **Console:**
>   [JENKINS] Archiving disabled
>   Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:perform (default-cli) on project Boom: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:perform (default-cli) on project Boom: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

My pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.boom</groupId>
    <artifactId>Boom</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Boom Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.7</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <scm>
        <connection>my repo</connection>
        <developerConnection>my repo</developerConnection>
        <url>url</url>
    </scm>
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Boom-releases</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <!--  Repo Maven  -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Boom-releases</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
.........
<build>
        <finalName>Boom</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://coconet-svn-fr-01.capgemini.com/svn/repos/test_amine/tags</tagBase>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

IS my pom file right? i have changed pom so many times but still build is failed and couldnot deploy artifacts in central repo.
I would appreciate if anyone help me to release maven.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have come across this questions and answers everywhere but no answers helps me to get build success and target folder generation.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to maven central? You can't do that - there's a documented process if you're publishing open source stuff. Otherwise you need your own repository manager for artefact deployment.

Comment: See here: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve for ur reply. Yeah am trying to deploy to central repo, because that is client requirment to deploy in central repo.Is there any possibilities to deploy over there? and if what is the procedure?and why the perform maven build is getting fail.?

Comment: Thanks Khmarbaise, i will refer that doc